# Pick a random item from a file then send it. Discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, bots, discord.js

I want to create a command for my bot so that when a certain command is issued, it will get a random quote from a json file and send it in chat.
I know how to do it with an array but I don't know how to do it from a file.
**EDIT:**
The code I have so far:

```
let question = args.slice(0).join(' ');
    if (!question)
    return message.reply("Please ask a question!");
    var sayings = [ ':8ball: Absolutly.',
                    ':8ball: Absolutly not.',
                    ':8ball: It is true.',
                    ':8ball: Impossible.',
                    ':8ball: Of course.',
                    ':8ball: I do not think so.',
                    ':8ball: It is true.',
                    ':8ball: It is not true.',
                    ':8ball: I am very undoubtful of that.',
                    ':8ball: I am very doubtful of that.',
                    ':8ball: Sources point to no.',
                    ':8ball: Theories prove it.',
                    ':8ball: Reply hazy try again.',
                    ':8ball: Ask again later.',
                    ':8ball: Better not tell you now.',
                    ':8ball: Cannot predict now.',
                    ':8ball: Concentrate and ask again.'
        ];

        var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * sayings.length) + 0);
        message.channel.send(sayings[result]);
```

Comment: So, the bot aspect is irrelevant, and all you need to know is how to load a file into an array in node.js? This should be easily googlable.

Comment: Could you show us your code that you have so far?

Comment: I have edited my question with the code I have at the moment.

Comment: Example of Json file I have:  
[
  {
    "Question": "What do you call a gnome priest",
    "Answer": "A compact disc"
  },
  {
    "Question": "Why does the best raiding guild smell so bad?",
    "Answer": "because they never wipe"
  }
]

Comment: Hi @Erkaloth, did you have any questions about the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js makes it easy to load JSON files

`const obj = require("../path/jsonfile.json");`

From your comment, `obj` will be an array of Question objects that you can manipulate like any ordinary array.

Further reading at:
https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/how-to-use-json-files-in-node-js-85hndqt32