# discord.js: randomise contents of array stored as json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, discord.js

I'm working on a small Discord bot to try and teach myself a bit of js, but I've run into something I can't really work out or find an answer to.

I have a command that has the bot post a quote at random from an array stored in a separate json file, and this works as intended.

```
var config = require("./settings.json");
var quotes = config.quotes;

function randomQuote() {
   return quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
};

if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "quote") {
   message.channel.send(randomQuote());
}
```

I'm now trying to do something similar, except rather than the array being a part of the json file, it *is* the json file. Essentially, the user can tell the bot to save a certain message, and it takes the message author & content and adds them as an entry to the array. It should then do the same as the quote function, randomise the entries in the array and then print one into the chat.

```
var mess;

let saveMess = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./saveMess.json", "utf8"));

function randomMess() {
    return saveMess[Math.floor(Math.random() * saveMess.length)];
};

if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "saveMess")) {
    mess = message.author + " told me the following:\n" + message.content;
    fs.readFile("./saveMess.json", function (err, data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data)
        json.push(mess)
        fs.writeFile("./saveMess.json", JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
            if (err) console.error(err)
        });
    })
}

if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "printMess") {
    message.channel.send(randomMess());
}
```

From my testing, I know it's being correctly stored in an array, and asking to print the entire file correctly (i.e. `message.channel.send(saveMess)`) displays all the saved entries; however, when attempting to do the same randomising function, I get the error "cannot send empty message". Clearly, there's something I'm missing that sets an array contained within a json file apart from an array that *is* a json file; does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this working as intended?

For clarification, here's how the two json files look, to demonstrate the difference I'm talking about:

```
//settings.json - the quote file

{ "token" : "BotTokenHere",
    "prefix" : "|",
    "quotes" : [
        "Quote 1",
        "Quote 2",
        "Quote 3"
    ]
}
```

---

```
//savemess.json - the saved messages file

[
    "<@user1> told me the following:\n|saveMess test",
    "<@user2> told me the following:\n|saveMess test2",
    "<@user3> told me the following:\n|saveMess test3"
]
```

Comment: Do you always get the error 'cannot send empty message' or only sometimes?

Comment: @DanielTate it's every time that an attempt is made.

Comment: you are doing every thing right, or so it seem at first sight, reading the file parsing it ..etc. well check first the encoding, that the json file is utf8 encoded. and try to debug the app, either using a debugger, using vscode for example. or using console.dir(saveMess), and for randomMess() . and that will clarify where is the problem. Make sure if the file is read or not, check the string. so save the output of readFileSync into a var, and ouput that to the console. Just debug and see where the problem reside

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick a random item from a file then send it. Discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034643/pick-a-random-item-from-a-file-then-send-it-discord-bot)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the JSON guidelines at [json.org](http://json.org), a json file must be an object, it cannot be an array. It is possible that `JSON.parse` is not throwing an error, however returning an empty array/object. You should stick with using the original `settings.json`.

Comment: That would explain it! Any idea how I'd get an array within a json file to add entries, then? I was originally trying to work out a way to do it like that, but I honestly couldn't find out how to target a specific array within a file to write to, thus trying to use a separate file tat was dedicated to that array.

Comment: Well  json can be an array, an array in javascript word is an object. and you can test it right away. So the problem is nothing about that. The first thing to do is to make sure you are getting the data. Your code to read the json file and parse it is all right. There can be a problem with the encoding. that the saved json isn't utf8 encoded. check that out. But what i suggest is to debug the application, you can do that with an appropriate debugger like configuring and using vscode debugger. or just quickly using console.dir, to print out the state of messMess, and randomMess()

Comment: Here to verify the statement about json and array
https://codepen.io/mohamedlamineallal/pen/zaaXXE